# Make input field visible if cloned select has a specific value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new to JQuery and don't have mich experience with Javascript either.
My goal is to allow the user to add a select element if he needs more and if he selected a specific option to display another input field right next to it. I got the cloning working but I am not able to display the input field.
My HTML:

```
<div class="right">
   <a href="#" id="addField">Add parameters</a><br>
   <label for="link[]" class="wrap"><span class="label">Parameter:</span>
      <select name="link[]" size="1" id="link">
        <option value="lang">lang</option>
        <option value="action">action</option>
        <option value="mode">mode</option>
        <option value="other">Other...</option>
      </select>
      <input type="text" name="other_link[]" style="display:none" class="params">-
      <input type="text" name="parameter[]">
      <a href="#" style="display:none;" class="remove">Remove</a><br>
    </label>
</div>
```

If the "Other..." option is selected I want to make the input with the class "params" visible.
My JQuery so far:

```
$(function(){
  var i = 1;

  // Add a clone
  $('#addField').click(function(){
    if(i < 6){
      $(".wrap").clone().attr('class','wrap'+i).appendTo(".right");
      $(".wrap"+i).children("select").attr('id','link_'+i);
      $(".wrap"+i).children("a").attr('style','display: inline;');
      $(".wrap"+i).children("input.params").attr('id','i_wrap'+i);
    }
    i++;
    return false;
   });

   // Remove a clone
   $(document).on('click', '.remove', function(e){
    $(this).parent().remove();
    i--;
   });

   // Make the input visible
   $("select").change(function(){
     parentID = $(this).parent().attr('class');
     if ($(this).val() === 'other'){ 
       $('.i_'+parentID).show();   
     } else {
       $('.i_'+parentID).hide(); 
     }
   });
});
```

My Goal here was to just bind the onchange to every select element but no element is responding so far...

[**JsFiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/qnLembmx/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way is to change a bit your function:

```
$("select").change(function(){
```

TO:

`$(document).on('change', "select", function(){
  parentID = $(this).parent().find('.params');
  if ($(this).val() === 'other'){
    parentID.show();
  } else {
    parentID.hide();
  }
});`

Answer (score 1):

I'd consider the following change:

```
function additionalField() {
    parentID = $(this).parent().attr('class');
    if ($(this).val() === 'other') {
      $(this).parent().find('input.params').show();
    } else {
      $(this).parent().find('input.params').hide();
    }
  }

// Make the input visible
$(document).off("change", 'select', additionalField);
$(document).on("change", 'select', additionalField);
```

Comment: will you accept the answer, in order to be clear for others

Comment: @JamieBarker I'll get that fixed but at least I now know how to do it

Answer (score 0):

Noobed's answer isn't correct. All "params" fields will show if one has been set to other.

You want to get the input relative to your select

```
$(document).on("change", 'select', function() {
  if ($(this).val() === 'other') {
    $(this).next().show();
  } else {
    $(this).next().hide();
  }
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/qnLembmx/3/